# How can I pass two params from controller to model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, web-applications

I want to pass two params that I am introducing in an input en the index view. This is what i have in the index (the style doesn´t matter):

```
<form action="/cars" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="From" value="<%= @from %>"/>
      <input type="text" name="to" placeholder="To" value="<%= @to %>"/>
      <input style="color:white; border-radius: 2px; padding: 10px; margin-right: 20px; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; background-color: black; " type="submit", value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

After this, in the cars_controller I have the following:

```
if params[:from] && params[:to]
      @cars = @cars.filter(params[:from, :to])
end
```

Finally in my model, i have my function that works with The :from and :to params in a specific way to filter the cars, it doesn´t matter what´s inside. My method is like the following:

```
def filter(from, to)
end
```

So the problem comes when, in the index view, I introduce the :from ant :to params by hand, press teh submit button and it returns me "wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @cars = @cars.filter(params[:from] , params[:to])
```